# R - How to make a stringi str_extract pattern parametric in a loop

Tags: r, regex, stringi

I have strings that are segmented by forward-slashes, I am trying to generate this using a loop so I need to parametrize the regex so that I can use it inside a loop. I have 7 levels:

I want to extract the followings using the regex and `stringi`:

```
A
A/268
A/268/200
A/268/200/300
A/268/200/300/400
```

Here's what I have:

```
n=3
str_extract("A/268/200/300/400/500","(.*?/){n}"


str_extract("A/268/200/300/400/500","(.*?/){3}"
```

Comment: If you storethe pattern. as. a vector `pat <- c("(.*/)", "\\d+"); lst1 <- vector('list', length(pat)); for(i in seq_along(pat) lst1[[i]] str_extract(yourvector, pat[i])`

Comment: Here, just split with `/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You mean split and then paste them in the loop as desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `glue::glue` to interpolate the values

```
n <- 3
pat <- as.character(glue::glue("(.*?/){<-n-1->}([^/]+)", 
               .open = "<-", .close = "->"))
pat
#[1] "(.*?/){2}([^/]+)"
library(stringr)
str_extract("A/268/200/300/400/500", pat)
#[1] "A/268/200"
```

---

If we need it as a  loop

```
v1 <- 1:7
lst1 <- vector('list', length(v1))
for(i in v1) {
   tmppat <- as.character(glue::glue("(.*?/){<-i-1->}([^/]+)",
                   .open = "<-", .close = "->"))
   lst1[[i]] <- str_extract("A/268/200/300/400/500", tmppat)
 }





head(lst1, 5)
#[[1]]
#[1] "A"

#[[2]]
#[1] "A/268"

#[[3]]
#[1] "A/268/200"

#[[4]]
#[1] "A/268/200/300"

#[[5]]
#[1] "A/268/200/300/400"
```

Comment: can you get rid of the last forward slash in the result? the regex should be modified

Comment: @lbo I was using your regex

Comment: @akurn I know, I could not come up with a regex to get rid of the last slash and I did not want to make the question complicated

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex` in `base` along with the `for` loop:

```r
for (n in 1:lengths(regmatches("A/268/200/300/400/500" , 
                                gregexpr("/", "A/268/200/300/400/500")))) {

  print(gsub(paste0("^(?:[^/]*\\K/){",n,"}.*"), "", "A/268/200/300/400/500", perl = TRUE))
}

#> [1] "A"
#> [1] "A/268"
#> [1] "A/268/200"
#> [1] "A/268/200/300"
#> [1] "A/268/200/300/400"
```

***First solution:***

In `base`, we can make a `regex` pattern and change `n` (possibly in a for-loop) to extract desired results:

```r
N <- lengths(regmatches("A/268/200/300/400/500" , gregexpr("/", "A/268/200/300/400/500")))
n <- 3

strsplit("A/268/200/300/400/500",paste0("([^/]+)(?:/[^/]+){",N-n,"}$"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A/268/200/"
```